# Strange Slow performance issue

Tags: magento-1.9, performance, optimization

We are using Magento CE 1.9 and the website is performing fine remotely and there were no performance complaints from external visitors or when we access it from our home network or wireless providers, but both storefront and admin site page load times are terribly slow when we access it behind our office network (wired internet connection, single public IP).

Is there any magento config setting or restriction that limits multiple user connections to the store front? Will whitelisting the IP makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem last month.

It was only our office network. Which triggered me thinking, ok, this might be our ip. Something is not getting pass through to our ip.

[This link will explain little bit of it.](https://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/NetworkAdmin/WebSitePerformance/)

Then I contacted our hosting provider and also ISP with my trace rout.

While doing tracerout I saw that there was blockade for our ip while routing though different pipes. It was showing timeout.

**To check trace route**

1. Open your command and type following

   ```
   tracert [your_ip_of_site or just domain.com]
   ```

This will give you an idea what's going on.

**How to fix?**

This part is very tricky, since it's not your magento having the problem, it's the network issue persist whether in your ISP or your hosting provider but they both deny of such.

**For quick fix, you can ask your ISP to change your ip to something else.** However you might be thinking, oh! wait what if my customer also having same issue as mine?

You simply need to contact your hosting provider and ISP to fix the issue.
Even my problem was resolved, no one said who's fault was it. I personally doubt it was my web hosting provider who's network routing was having issue.

**[UPDATE]**

You can also ask your web hosting provider to do `reverse trace route` to your `local ip`. This will help you to convince the problem persist in their end.

Comment: Thank you Adarsh for the prompt feedback. Let me run the suggested tests. We had the Ping disabled on our server, will check with hosting provider on the reverse trace route option too. Thank you.

Comment: Any luck with you @Ben?